# Escape Single Quotes in HiveSQL

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a basic query that runs successfully in HUE but not in RazorSQL (IDE). I have tried multiple ways of escaping the single quote, but to no avail.

```
select * from table where channel_name = "This isn't it"; --what I want to run and runs successfully in HUE

--the following returns me nothing or give me an error
select * from table where channel_name = "This isn"'t it";
select * from table where channel_name = "This isn\'t it";

select * from table where channel_name = This isn"'t it';
select * from table where channel_name = 'This isn\'t it';
```

Comment: Hi @Bala, that executed, but returned nothing. :(

Comment: https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Hive-statement-INSERT-INTO-X-VALUES-does-not-escape-as/td-p/66828

Comment: https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Escaping-Single-Quote-in-Hive/td-p/66821

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the answer to my own questions. Hive SQL in RazorSQL (or maybe any other IDE) does not like semicolons at the end of the query.

So instead of 
         select * from table where channel_name = "This isn't it";
do
         select * from table where channel_name = "This isn't it"